# How to see if the user already exist on parse?

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, dynamic-queries

I tried this, but it doens't work

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("_User")
    .WhereEqualTo("email", SPFacebook.instance.userInfo.email);

query.CountAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
    int count = t.Result;
    Debug.Log(count);
});
```

Any suggetions ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your User table. As a testing step, can you hardcode an email into your query, i.e WhereEqualTo("email","foo@example.com") where you know that foo@example.com is set in the email field of an existing user.

Comment: Also, given that you are using swift here, I'm guessing this is client side, not server code. Unless you have the master key loaded (which you can only do in CloudCode), you can't query for other users.